# SetState not rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, setstate

So I am working on my React app and a one point i need to upload some files. So I simply used the `input file`   to make it work. I set its display none as I wanted my attachment icon to be clicked when wanting to upload the file.

Problem : Using the ref method, everything is working fine except one thing and that is below in my hangleFileChange function, when the setFiles() set the file variable, the component is not rendered and I do not see the file array. but if I do the file saving simply like

```
setFile(event.target.files[0])
```

I can see the rendering . But with the below code, the component is not rendering

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const fileInput = useRef(null);
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Make something");
    let newFiles = file;
    newFiles.push(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(newFiles);
    setFile(newFiles);
  };

  // This should run on every render
  console.log("the files array is ", file);
  return (
    <div className="patientactions-container">
      <input
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)}
        ref={fileInput}
      />
      <div onClick={() => handleClick()}>clck</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Please help.

Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-breeze-czc3w?file=/src/App.js:0-692

Comment: If i understand you well, yo want to push the file to the variable **ne** right?

Comment: the variable is just temporary variable. I want to append the new file the user has uploaded to my file array. So I took a temp variable 'ne' and copied the values of file. Then i pushed the new file and then setFile(ne). you got it ?

Comment: Let me post it in the answer

Comment: I changed the code and used 
setFile ( [ ...file, event.target.files[0] ] ) ;
And now it is rendering. But I still not get why the above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

```
const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Make something");
    // Set the ne variable to an array, not file
    let ne = [];
    ne.push(event.target.files[0]);
    // then set it equals file.
    ne = file;
    console.log(ne);
    console.log(file);
    setFile(file);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the code like this below.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const fileInput = useRef(null);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

  const handleFileChange = (nfile) => {
    console.log("Make something");
    if (file == null) setFile([nfile]);
    else setFile([...file, nfile]);
  };
  console.log("the files array", file);
  return (
    <div className="patientactions-container">
      <input
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e.target.files[0])}
        ref={fileInput}
      />
      <div onClick={() => handleClick()}>clck</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Yes I did the same thing as above and it is re-rendering fine. But I want to know what is wrong in my handleFileChange function as it is also doing the same thing.

Comment: it is because  from the start, file is empty and you're setting a new file to an empty array... remember the code reads from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

I'd have put this in the comments but my rep is not high enough.

I had a problem with rendering changes to an array, because arrays use pointers it did not "register" a state change that was enough to cause a render. Using the spread operator in your solution affected the pointer and thus a render occurred.

In my own solution I set my array to null before adding content and that worked fine for my problem.